# Can I place vim cursor into specific windows?

Tags: vim, window, cursor

Let's assume that your vim window has been split into many windows horizontally and vertically.
And your vim has the tagbar plugin window on the left and the nerdtree plugin window on the right.
So the many split windows are in between those two - the tagbar and the nerdtree.
In this circumstances, you want to move your cursor from anywhere into the tagbar window at ONE nmapped key stroke. And you want to move your cursor from anywhere into the nerdtree window at another ONE nmapped key stroke.
How can you do this? How would you write your .vimrc for this?

Answer (score 0):

CTRL-W t places cursor into the upper-left-most window

CTRL-W b places cursor into the lower-right-most window

Comment: Both commands are mentioned in `:help usr_08`, chapter 8 of the user manual.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
" Use ctrl-[hjkl] to select the active split!
nmap <silent> <c-k> :wincmd k<CR>
nmap <silent> <c-j> :wincmd j<CR>
nmap <silent> <c-h> :wincmd h<CR>
nmap <silent> <c-l> :wincmd l<CR>
```

So you can now move up, down, left, right with `hjkl` keys.

Move up `Ctrl + k`.
Move down `Ctrl + j`.
Move left `Ctrl + h`.
Move right `Ctrl + l`.

Comment: I did similar key-map (noremap <C-H> <C-W>h) My question was a key-map that moves my cursor right a way at one key sequence stroke like this - CTRL-W t